# Basic Probability Concept Confusion

Tags: probability

I am preparing for my Probability exam, and there is a question that is really bugging me, I am unable to get a reasonable response yet, so I am posting it here!

I know that probability of any event can not be more than 1. Now consider an example, there are three snipers, each sniper has a probability 1/2 of hitting the target. Now if these snipers simultaneously take a shot, what will be the probability of target being it?

My take is it should be, 1/2 + 1/2 + 1/2 but that makes the probability more than 1, err..., any response will be highly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: 1/2 + 1/2 + 1/2 is the mean number of snipers hitting the target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any probability is a number between $0$ and $1$.

If we want to calculate the probability of target being hit at least once, we can proceed as follows. We assume that the sniper shots are independent. The probability of target not being hit is given by $(1/2)^3$ (each sniper misses). The probability of target being hit at least once is thus given by
$$
1-(1/2)^3=0.875.
$$

Comment: Let me tweak a question bit now, consider only 1 sniper is there, and his P(Sniper hitting) = 1/2, then, will conditional P(Target Hit | Sniper hitting) = 1/2 too? Because I believe P(Sniper hitting) essentially mean P(Target been hit if Sniper fires), sorry but this probability thing has made me a real mess!

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you mean. $P(\text{Target Hit}\mid\text{Sniper hitting})=1$ since if the sniper hits the target, the target is hit. We don't consider such events as sniper firing the gun. I hope it makes a little bit clearer.